# Diferença entre [i] + 1 e [i + 1]

Tags: c, lógica

Tenho dúvidas em relação `[i] + 1` e `[i + 1]`, um incrementa posição e o outro conteúdo, correto?

Em relação a notação `(*i)++`, ela é similar a qual das duas citadas acima?

Answer (score 6):

> Tenho dúvidas em relação `[i] + 1` e `[i + 1]`, um incrementa posição e o outro conteúdo, correto?

Na verdade a primeira, o `[i] +1`, devolve o que está na posição somado de `1`.

Ao passo que a segunda, o `[i + 1]`, devolve a posição somada de `1`.

Nenhuma delas incrementa de facto o valor a menos que faça uma atribuição na mesma instrução, assim:

```
arr[i] = arr[i] + 1
```

Logo não seria correto dizer que incrementa.

> Em relação a notação `(*i)++`, ela é similar a qual das duas citadas acima?

Nenhuma pois você está a utilizar o operador de incremento `++` e por isso seria equivalente a fazer `[i]++`.

Equivalente a de `[i] +1` seria `*i + 1`, e equivalente a `[i + 1]` seria `*(i+1)`.